# Создание нескольких handler`ов

Tags: сервер, golang, handlers

Мне необходимо создать объект стандартного сервера, у которого есть несколько handler'ов, но почему-то у стандартного объекта golang-server'а есть только 1 поле для handler`а.

```
http.Server{
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(mockServer.handlerGetCutOffTimeV2),
}
```

Каким образом создать аналогичный объект с несколькими хендлерами?

Comment: Научитесь уже писком пользоваться https://www.google.ru/search?q=golang+http+router&rlz=1C1CHBD_enRU800RU800&oq=golang+http+router&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.5167j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Bleser не нужно на меня собак срывать. Я говорю про стандартный сервер го. Вопрос поправил. Гитхабовские репо смотреть умею. Но они мне ни к чему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net/http.(*ServeMux)` является хендлером. Так что:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/api/", apiHandler{})
mux.Handle("/web/", webHandler{})
srv := &http.Server{
    Handler: mux,
}
```